# LEGO Friends drinking bottle (850817) containing BPA?

Tags: friends, accessories

LEGO has recently released Friends drinking bottle [850817](http://brickset.com/sets/850817-1/Drinking-Bottle), but there's no mention anywhere (not on the product itself, not on the [product's web page](http://shop.lego.com/en-GB/Drinking-Bottle-850817?fromListing=listing)) as to whether the product contains BPA ([Bisphenol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisphenol_A)), a dangerous chemical (especially for children) commonly used in bottles.

Question: Does this product contain BPA?

---

**Edit:** This is not a duplicate question because it concerns a drinking bottle released in 2016, not vintage LEGO bricks. In addition, please note that the bottom of product 850817 has a recycling symbol [with the number 7](http://www.fda.gov/Food/IngredientsPackagingLabeling/FoodAdditivesIngredients/ucm355155.htm):

> **How Can You Tell if a Container Has BPA?**
>   A resin code of 7 appearing on plastic containers indicates that the container may be made of a BPA-containing plastic. (U.S. Food and Drug Administration)

[image: Bottle]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BPA in older Lego](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/7471/bpa-in-older-lego)

Comment: http://www.fda.gov/Food/IngredientsPackagingLabeling/FoodAdditivesIngredients/ucm355155.htm ... http://reason.com/blog/2015/01/21/bpa-safe-yet-another-scientifically-unfo

Comment: This is a question about a specific water bottle, rather than LEGO bricks in general as in the possible duplicate, so I'm going to leave it open.

Comment: I have now been in touch with official LEGO representatives, but they were unable to give a satisfactory answer to the question. It appears it cannot be ruled out that these bottles contain BPA.

Answer (score 1):

Remember the BPA scare? It's all but a crime to release a product that even *thinks* about having BPA. But I did the search anyway, and no, there is not any in this or any other LEGO product I can find to date. LEGO is pretty good about nontoxic products, drinking use intended or no. I mean, they're made for kids. Good question though.

Comment: Where did you find your information?

Comment: http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/7471/bpa-in-older-lego is one source, and well cited.

Comment: This question is not about Lego bricks, it is about a drinking bottle.

Comment: I checked the bottle, too, just also mentioning that source. I talked to a friend from LEGO team, and no, no drinking products of theirs contain BPA.